# C++; instantiating multiple instances of a class results in memory error

Tags: c++, memory, runtime-error

Here is my source.cpp:

```
#include "BST.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    BST<int> test1;
    BST<int> test2;
    test1.insert(10);
    test1.insert(15);
    test1.insert(12);
    test1.insert(14);
    test1.insert(19);
    test1.test();
    cout << test1.contain(1) << endl;
    cout << test1.isEmpty() << endl;
    //cout << test2.isEmpty() << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my header file:

```
//Haris
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"

template <typename Comparable>
class BST
{
public:
    int size = 0;
    int currentRootindex = 0;
    BST(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            data[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    ~BST(){

    }

    void insert(Comparable obj){


        if (data[0] == NULL){
            data[0] = obj;
            size++;


        }
        else{

            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++){
                if (data[currentRootindex] < obj && data[(2 * currentRootindex) + 2] == NULL){
                    data[(2 * currentRootindex) + 2] = obj;
                    size++;


                    break;
                }
                else if (data[currentRootindex] >= obj && data[(2 * currentRootindex) + 1] == NULL){
                    data[(2 * currentRootindex) + 1] = obj;


                    size++;
                    break;
                }
                else if (data[currentRootindex] < obj){
                    currentRootindex = ((2 * currentRootindex) + 2);


                }
                else{
                    currentRootindex = ((2 * currentRootindex) + 1);


                }

            }
        }
        currentRootindex = 0;
    }
    bool isEmpty(){
        if (data[0] == NULL){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool contain(Comparable obj){
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++){
             if (data[currentRootindex] < obj){
                currentRootindex = ((2 * currentRootindex) + 2);


            }
             else if (data[currentRootindex] > obj){
                 currentRootindex = ((2 * currentRootindex) + 1);


             }
             else
                 return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
    void test(){

        cout << data[5] << endl;


    }


private:
    Vector<Comparable> data;

};
```

if I comment out the `BST<int>test2` from source.cpp, the code works as intended.
But when i instantiate `BST<int>test2` after `BST<int>test1`, I get `Application Error: The memory could not be read`. I have not declared any static variables, so none of the variables is being shared across different objects.

Also, the Vector header file, I am using is

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Object>
class Vector
{
public:
    explicit Vector( int initSize = 0 )
    : theSize{ initSize }, theCapacity{ initSize + SPARE_CAPACITY }
    { objects = new Object[ theCapacity ]; }

    Vector( const Vector & rhs )
    : theSize{ rhs.theSize }, theCapacity{ rhs.theCapacity }, objects{ nullptr }
    {
        objects = new Object[ theCapacity ];
        for( int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k )
            objects[ k ] = rhs.objects[ k ];
    }

    Vector & operator= ( const Vector & rhs )
    {
        Vector copy = rhs;
        std::swap( *this, copy );
        return *this;
    }

    ~Vector( )
    { delete [ ] objects; }

    Vector( Vector && rhs )
    : theSize{ rhs.theSize }, theCapacity{ rhs.theCapacity }, objects{ rhs.objects }
    {
        rhs.objects = nullptr;
        rhs.theSize = 0;
        rhs.theCapacity = 0;
    }

    Vector & operator= ( Vector && rhs )
    {
        std::swap( theSize, rhs.theSize );
        std::swap( theCapacity, rhs.theCapacity );
        std::swap( objects, rhs.objects );

        return *this;
    }

    bool empty( ) const
    { return size( ) == 0; }
    int size( ) const
    { return theSize; }
    int capacity( ) const
    { return theCapacity; }

    Object & operator[]( int index )
    {
        return objects[ index ];
    }

    const Object & operator[]( int index ) const
    {
        return objects[ index ];
    }

    void resize( int newSize )
    {
        if( newSize > theCapacity )
            reserve( newSize * 2 );
        theSize = newSize;
    }

    void reserve( int newCapacity )
    {
        if( newCapacity < theSize )
            return;

        Object *newArray = new Object[ newCapacity ];
        for( int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k )
            newArray[ k ] = std::move( objects[ k ] );

        theCapacity = newCapacity;
        std::swap( objects, newArray );
        delete [ ] newArray;
    }

    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back( const Object & x )
    {
        if( theSize == theCapacity )
            reserve( 2 * theCapacity + 1 );
        objects[ theSize++ ] = x;
    }
    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back( Object && x )
    {
        if( theSize == theCapacity )
            reserve( 2 * theCapacity + 1 );
        objects[ theSize++ ] = std::move( x );
    }

    void pop_back( )
    {
        --theSize;
    }

    const Object & back ( ) const
    {
        return objects[ theSize - 1 ];
    }

    // Iterator stuff: not bounds checked
    typedef Object * iterator;
    typedef const Object * const_iterator;

    iterator begin( )
    { return &objects[ 0 ]; }
    const_iterator begin( ) const
    { return &objects[ 0 ]; }
    iterator end( )
    { return &objects[ size( ) ]; }
    const_iterator end( ) const
    { return &objects[ size( ) ]; }

    static const int SPARE_CAPACITY = 2;

private:
    int theSize;
    int theCapacity;
    Object * objects;
};

#endif
```

[image: Error]

Comment: So what did your debugger say?

Comment: Who do you think would allocate vector<T>?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use vector - continuously allocated memory for a data structure like Tree.

Comment: @SemyonBurov There is evidence to suggest that the better locality and cache friendliness of vector wins in a lot of common use cases, even when other data structures have better asymptotic guarantees for inserts.

Comment: @Tim Seguine It isn't common use case. Structure of binary search tree is exactly determined by the sequence of stored values. If some branch of tree would overweighted vector would require hellish amount of memory and most of it wouldn't be used. This is question of understanding

Comment: @SemyonBurov You can encode a binary search tree (actually any partially ordered set) easily and efficiently with a sorted vector of ordered pairs. The first item in the ordered pair represents the key, and the second element represents the value. This uses the same amount of space as the explicit tree representation. Search is still logarithmic but insertion becomes asymptotically linear in the tree size. Linear insertion is the only downside, in many cases, the improved cache friendliness and locality outweigh this.

Comment: @Tim Seguine We can use simple vector of elements from start, keep it sorted by linear insertions and we can use binary search on it, its O(log n). Without any pairs. With all cache friendliness that it can give us. But we are talking about binary search tree and in this scope vector is useless, nonoptimal memory eater.

Comment: @SemyonBurov Whatever. I already explained how to do it without wasting memory. It's not my problem if you don't want to listen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing out of bounds indices of the data vector. The default vector constructor initialises with size 0 (although it allocates 2 extra elements) but then you immediately try to access up to index 999:

```
BST(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        data[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

The second object isn't really related to the problem. Even with only one object, the code is still accessing memory it shouldn't.

Changing the data vector to initialise with size 1000 fixes the out of bounds errors for this particular code, but I suspect the BST class will cause more of these errors in future because I can't see any checks against the data vector's size.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
   data.push_back(NULL);
  }